# Access array of database values outside of loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I can loop through a table, grab the rows and echo them out within the loop. How do I use this data outside the loop?

```
$query=("SELECT * FROM poplinks");
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $popid = $row['popid'];
    $popname = $row['popname'];
    $popurl = $row['popurl'];

echo $popurl;
}
```

The echo statement above echos the 10 popurl values in the db, but if I try and echo $popurl outside of the loop I only get the last value. I guess I want an array of all the values stored in a variable.

Update:
The data is going into something like the below HTML: (note "echo $popurl" on line 3. The idea is to get the Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead function to read from a database. At the moment by appending [] to each of the variables inside the loop, I can get the below code working if I include the index e.g.  but I can't get the entire row in there.

```
<div class="well">
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="proceed();">
<input type="text" class="span3" name="content" value="<?php echo $liLink->sContent; ?>" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Alabama", "<?php echo $popurl ?>" ,"Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas"]'/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Comment: As pointed out by @Abid Hussain, store the value of popurl in an array so that on every loop, the value gets appended and not overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$query=("SELECT * FROM poplinks");
$result = mysql_query($query);

$myArray='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $popid = $row['popid'];
    $popname = $row['popname'];
    $popurl = $row['popurl'];

$myArray[] = $popurl;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
```